# Google Drive API: Where or How to find Shared Drive ID?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google's APIs Explorer to run a method (`drive.permissions.create`) in which I  grant a user access to an entire Google Shared Drive (not specifically a file or folder).

[image]

After executing the command, I get the following error:

`An error occurred. See the response for details.`

**Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0AKppN1yZFzBbUk9PVA/permissions?emailMessage=Test&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "role": "organizer",
 "type": "user",
 "emailAddress": "test@test.com"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
   "error":{
      "errors":[
         {
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"notFound",
            "message":"File not found: 0AKppN1yZFzBbUk9PVA.",
            "locationType":"parameter",
            "location":"fileId"
         }
      ],
      "code":404,
      "message":"File not found: 0AKppN1yZFzBbUk9PVA."
   }
}
```

I acquired value, 0AKppN1yZFzBbUk9PVA, from another command I thought would give me the ID of the Shared Drive I'm trying to share(drive.drives.list). However, this value is incorrect. Where or how can I find the ID of the Shared Drive I'm trying to give access to?

Also, if I'm missing another value to input other than a correct Id for the command to be successful, please let me know. There is still so much I don't know about how Google Drive's API works (or APIs for that matter).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For Shared Drives you need to set `supportsAllDrives` to `true`.